# My Java regex never matches despite it always passes on online java regex checker

Tags: java, regex

My regex: `(VSHORT:(?<VSHORT>[^,]+))*,*(SHORT:(?<SHORT>[^,]+))*,*(MED:(?<MED>[^,]+))*,*(LONG:(?<LONG>[^,]+))*`

sample text: `VSHORT:Ar,SHORT:Arsnl`

Java code:

```
 Pattern.compile("(VSHORT:(?<VSHORT>[^,]+))*,*(SHORT:(?<SHORT>[^,]+))*,*(MED:(?<MED>[^,]+))*,*(LONG:(?<LONG>[^,]+))*")
        .matcher("VSHORT:Ar,SHORT:Arsnl")
        .group("SHORT");
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
```

I tried with several online regex tester like https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output and always passed.

Can someone please help what can be the problem?

Comment: Lesson to learn: You often find a good answer faster through your search engine than through posting a new question on Stack Overflow. So try the search engine first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call [**`Matcher::find`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) method like this :

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(VSHORT:(?<VSHORT>[^,]+))*,*(SHORT:(?<SHORT>[^,]+))*,*(MED:(?<MED>[^,]+))*,*(LONG:(?<LONG>[^,]+))*")
        .matcher("VSHORT:Ar,SHORT:Arsnl");

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group("SHORT"));
}
```

Output

```
Arsnl
```

---

**Note :** If you wait more results you have to use `while` loop to get all matches results.

Comment: Thank you so much it works.

Comment: two successive down-vote this is strange, can you please explain? does my answer wrong?

Comment: I didn’t downvote. My giess is that it’s because in case of duplicate questions it’s better to mark them as duplicates and not answer them. If you think the answers under the original questions are insufficient, you can always add an answer there.